# Sample GUI - wxWidgest erlang

Tags: user-interface, button, erlang, wxwidgets, sample

I'm not sure this is the forum but i'm searching for a sample code to download and start with which creates a basic GUI with elementary buttons in erlang.

Sorry again for getting out of scope, please redirect me to the right section/webs if you know any.

Answer (score 1):

[wxErlang](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/wx/index.html) might be what you need.

Other lecture (and google should provide even more):

[wxErlang - Getting Started](https://arifishaq.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/wxerlang-getting-started.pdf)

[wxErlang - Speeding Up](https://arifishaq.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/wxerlang-speeding-up.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It is not the right place to ask this kind of question. The forum is meant to solve coding problem, not to get general information.

Nevertheless, using vxErlang is not always easy. I recommend you to use the [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/) documentation, of course it is not applicable directly to wxErlang, but it really helps a lot.

You can also consider to use [wxFormbuilder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/). It is a freeware that can generates xrc files from a wysiwyg interface. The file can then be used by wxErlang and produces very good results. It seems that the project is not really active now, but the current version is pretty complete and stable.

There is a good xrc example in the wxErlang library showing most of the features available.

Comment: Than you for your guidance!
Yes I tried the wxFormBuilder but where should I be implementing the onClick funcs? They don't appear in the xrc file.
Also, can you please elaborate more about the last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the already mentioned wxErlang URLs mentioned here, the Erlang and with it OTP library installation include the "wx.demo" application which lists several wx-widgets on the left, an example of their appearance and between those two representations the related program-code is available, it can be easily copied and used. Below the steps to start the demo-application and a screen-shot.

PS C:> erl
Eshell V12.0  (abort with ^G)
1> wx:demo().

[wxErlang Widget Demo Application - part of the Erlang/OTP installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d86mQ.png)